# 8 characters recognized as 9 in if statement

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, character

I'm trying to make an if-statement to see if the name equals a specific word. The name is only 8 characters long so I can only compare it to words that are 8 or less characters.

But the problem I'm getting it is that if I compare the two values I get this error:

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
>   'std::array'

When I remove one letter from the string I want to compare it to it doesn't give the error any more. But it doesn't seem to make sense to me why visual studio thinks there's 9 characters while there's only 8. I used the comparison before to check for a string of only 4 characters and that seemed to work fine.

```
if (lumps[i + h].name == TFixedString<8>{"LINEDEFS"})
{

}
```

Comment: This looks like `c++` or something to me based on error message, not `c#`.

Comment: What is `TFixedString` defined as? And `lumps[i + h].name`, is that a std::string?

Comment: @user3678781 Types don't matter to you?

Comment: `"LINEDEFS"` actually contains 8 characters plus the terminating `'\0'` character. Hence 9.

Comment: Hmm how could I compare then when the name I want to compare to seems to be 9 characters? And I just realized that I put C instead of C++, my mistake

Comment: @LogicStuff That comment doesn't really explain what my problem is, I'm pretty sure it's of the same type. I'm fairly new to C++ coding like this so don't act like the problem is obvious as it might not be obvious for me. Someone pointed out about the terminating character which I didn't know about, but now I don't know how to still compare with the terminating character included.

Comment: @user3678781 Well, what about `TFixedString<9>{"LINEDEFS"}` then?

Comment: then I'm comparing a char array with 8 characters to an array with 9 characters. I decided to solve it by making a char array with 8 characters instead of trying to convert a string to a char array. Like this     TFixedString<8> name = { 'L','I','N','E','D','E','F','S' };

Comment: @user3678781 That comment was to indicate that we can't give you answers based on one code snipped, without knowing what is what.

Comment: I see, well I solved it now in some way, maybe not the best, too bad I can't remove posts. I didn't see I posted in C instead of C++. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3678781 You can remove posts, as long there's no upvoted answer.

Comment: If `name` is actually a char array as you say, you must be very careful doing comparisons with it using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

All arrays start at 0 so if you have an array of 8, it will actually be 9.

Comment: What? No. `int a[10];` gives you 10 elements, indexed from 0 to 9.

Comment: What I mean is, if you have an array of 5 and you want to print out a name, let's say 'James', it will only print out 'Jame' because the null terminator will need a space in the array

Comment: @ProgStudent If you meant that, that's what you should have said.